# World map with states and providences drawn (with jVectorMap)

Tags: jvectormap

I am using jVectorMap with the world map.  I would like to draw lines inside of countries to divide states and providences.  The state and providences do not need to be individually selectable (ie do not need to be separate "regions") - it is mainly for aesthetic display purposes, and to give the user some context when zooming into the USA.

Other people solve this problem with multiple maps.  So a world map is displayed initially, and if you click the USA, it swaps out the world map for a USA map.  For this project, though, it would be nice to have just one map.

One idea I had was to set a background image on the USA path - [this feature is planned but not implemented](https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/issues/64), but there are a few ways this could be done in SVG without too much work.

Any suggestions / examples on how to draw providences inside countries on a world map?

Comment: I don't know how jVectorMap works, but all the data you are looking for is here: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

Comment: i also want to implement something something similar, anything you got to work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, how to add a SVG image to background. What I would do is to incorporate the USA Regional map paths into world-mill map, where US is placed.

You can do it in this manner:

```
"US": {"path": "M892.72,99.2l1.31,0.53l1.41,..., <USA-REGION-PATH-PART>",
"name": "United States"}
```

is the copied part of path from US Region Map.